# When duplicating lower-level spells with Wish/Primal Phenomenon/etc., what level is the duplicated spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, wish

When duplicating spells with the L10 spells of each tradition, are those cast at their lowest level or is it possible to heighten to the highest level allowed, based on their type (i.e., duplicating Arcane spells with Wish allows heightening up to level 9; but duplicating spells in other traditions allows heightening up to L7, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valid spells can be duplicated at any level allowed- a ninth level fireball, for instance, is an Arcane spell of 9th level or lower, and so can be duplicated by Wish.